# What kind of growing function has a constant as limit?

Tags: limits, functions

My knowledge in mathematics are a bit old and I'm looking for functions with constant as limit. The function must always grow.
The curve should be something similar to $\sqrt{x}$ or $\ln(x)$ but with $\lim _{x\to \infty \:}f\left(x\right)=\mathrm{constant}$

Could you please help to find this kind of functions?

Comment: Do you mean [logistic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function)? Or maybe you mean the [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) for a (real-valued) random variable $X$?

Comment: The function must be bounded, like $3-e^{-x}<3$ or $\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(x+1)}<1$ or $\arctan(x)<\pi/2$.

Comment: $y=a \tan^{-1}(bx+c)+d$, $y=a \tanh(bx+c)+d$ may be

Comment: @travis: is your example-function growing ? And if I am right, $f(x)<1$ for all $x>0$.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I didn't parse "growing" as "increasing", cheers.

Comment: $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{5x-1}{x}$ over $]0;+\infty[$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simplest way is to consider any decreasing function such that its limit is $0$, like $\frac{1}{x+1}$ or $e^{-x}$, and subtract from a constant :

$$C-\frac{1}{x^2+1}$$
$$C-e^{-3x}$$

Comment: But didn't OP ask for increasing functions?

Comment: @ColdNumber that's why I say "substract" !

Comment: Whoops! you're right.

Comment: @Xoff Better say: subtract.

Comment: @CiaPan Yes, sorry, I'm not so good in english sometimes

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to have some functions with the asked properties, you can easily construct one as Xoff pointed out. If you are looking for a class of functions (possibly from applied mathematics), the [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) $$f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R,~f(x)=\frac{L}{1+e^{-k(x-x_0)}}$$ might be something you are looking for (for the meaning of the constants $L,k,x_0$ consider the wikipedia page, it has lots of information on this).

If your familiar with stochastics and random variables, you could take a look at the [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function). It is monotonicically non-decreasing with $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$.

Answer (score 2):

An example could be $f(x)=-1/x$. It grows toward 0, its asymptote.

EDIT: As Hirshy pointed out, $f$ is not an increasing function if its domain is $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

So, define $f : \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=-1/x$.

This function increases monotonically: If $a>b>0$, then $1/a<1/b$, and $-1/a>-1/b$, which means that $a>b \implies f(a)>f(b)$.

Comment: But this function is only monotonic on either $\mathbb R^*_-$ or $\mathbb R^*_+$, so only on restricted domains.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I'm editing my answer.

Comment: @pjs36 for the $\ln(x)$ example the domain is $D=\mathbb R_+^*$ and $f$ is monotonic on its (full) domain. This is not the case with $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ which IMO is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Functions of $x$: $$-e^{-x}$$ $$ -x^{-1}$$ $$\cos \tfrac 1x \ \ \text{for}\ x > \tfrac 1\pi $$ $$\arctan x$$ all are monotonically growing and have finite limit as $x\to\infty$.